# Angular query animation resets style after animation finishes

Tags: angular, animation, group

When I trigger the following 2 parallel animations for nested elements, setting maximize[0] from false to true, the animation itself looks good. However the style of the element animated with the query part is reset after animation finishes so in this case jumps back to ***flex-basis: 0%;*** The style of the parent element stays like expected at ***calc(2*var(--card-width))***.

```
export const resizeTrigger = trigger('resizeTrigger', [
  state(
    'false',
    style({
      width: 'var(--card-width)',
    })
  ),
  state(
    'true',
    style({
      width: 'calc(2*var(--card-width))',
    })
  ),
  transition('false <=> true', [
    group([
      animate('2.5s ease-in-out'),
      query(
        '.my-test',
        [
          animate(
            '2.5s',
            keyframes([
              style({ 'flex-basis': '5%' }),
              style({ 'flex-basis': '50%' }),
            ])
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ]),
  ]),
]);
```

This is my template to test it:

```
<div
  style="height: 5rem; width: var(--card-width); border: 1px solid red; display: flex"
  [@resizeTrigger]="maximize[0]"
  (click)="onMaximize(0)"
>
  <div style="flex-grow: 1; height: 100%; background-color: pink"></div>
  <div
    class="my-test"
    style="
      display: block;
      overflow: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      background-color: blue;
    "
  >
    <span style="white-space: nowrap">this is a test</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this the scss:

```
* {
  --card-width: 10rem;
}
.my-test {
  flex-basis: 0%;
}
```

Does anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong here? I'm trying to get parallel animations on nested elements to work properly.

Using css animations and ngClass would work but shouldn't this work with angular animations too?